# Use routing from Angular Components in Hybrid mode

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, hybrid

I'm using AngularJS 1.5 and Angular 7 in hybrid mode. How can I change the url in an Angular component? I tried like to access the current url as follows:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);

}
```

The query parameters are always empty. In a parent AngularJS component I get the query parameters using the `$location` service.
If I try to change the route using the router, it says invalid route. How can I change the current url in an Angular component? Currently I'm emitting an event, which in turn is grabbed by the parent AngularJS component who can use the `$location` service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by upgrading the AngularJS $location service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocationService {

    search(queryParameter?: string, value?: string): string | any {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

In AppModule do the following

```
{provide: LocationService, useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('$location'), deps: ['$injector']},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following way to get the query params :

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params);
   });
}
```

to navigate to other url (as you specified, ie to change url ) then use:

```
this.router.navigate(['/someurl']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that this is the way in Angular. It does not work in Hybrid mode because my routes are defined in an AngularJS route file.